# IF statement using AND and OR conditions together - R

Tags: r, if-statement, logic

I am looking at some code which reads like this

```
if(X[i] && Y[i] == 'string1' || 'string2' || 'string3'){
do thing
}
```

The idea being, if both `X` and `Y` match any of the three strings, the statement executes.

When I read it aloud it makes sense to me but clearly the syntax is wrong.

Comment: Just no. I would post an answer, but I don't think I could keep it short enough. You should do some research in to how conditions work, and also order of precedence. I feel you are at a stage where a short answer would not help you, you need to go back to the basic and go through some tutorials (doesn't even need to be with R, just programming logic in general)

Comment: @musefan I am new to programming you are right, but I am well aware the logic here is completely off. I just wasn't sure how else to ask the question.

Comment: When you read this aloud, you should read it as *"If X[i] is true AND Y[i] is true, and that result (TRUE) is equal to the result of (is 'string1' or 'string2' or 'string3' true?).* It's complete nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `%in%` value matching and then check if `all` elements of the first vector are in the second vector where `c(argument_1,argument_2,etc)` combines arguments to form a vector.

```
all(c(X[i],Y[i]) %in% c('string1','string2','string3'))
```

Comment: This solves it, Thank you